# "Switch to specific workspace" shortcuts don't work after a reboot

Tags: compiz, shortcut-keys

i've defined some shortcuts to access each of my workspaces:

```
<Super>+1 for the First
<Super>+2 for the Second
etc...
```

when I assign these shortcuts, they function properly until I reboot. I have no idea why it's happening.

For some reason, On the desktop I have at work (same distrib, 10.10), it works fine.

To make them function again, I need to un-asign all of them, and then reasigning them again.

I have a script which automate these operations:

```
gconftool-2 --unset /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/switch_to_workspace_1
gconftool-2 --unset /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/switch_to_workspace_2
gconftool-2 --unset /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/switch_to_workspace_3
gconftool-2 --unset /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/switch_to_workspace_4
gconftool-2 --unset /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/switch_to_workspace_5
gconftool-2 --unset /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/switch_to_workspace_6
gconftool-2 --unset /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/switch_to_workspace_7
gconftool-2 --unset /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/switch_to_workspace_8

gconftool-2 -t str --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/switch_to_workspace_1 "<Mod4>ampersand"
gconftool-2 -t str --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/switch_to_workspace_2 "<Mod4>eacute"
gconftool-2 -t str --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/switch_to_workspace_3 "<Mod4>quotedbl"
gconftool-2 -t str --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/switch_to_workspace_4 "<Mod4>apostrophe"
gconftool-2 -t str --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/switch_to_workspace_5 "<Mod4>parenleft"
gconftool-2 -t str --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/switch_to_workspace_6 "<Mod4>minus"
gconftool-2 -t str --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/switch_to_workspace_7 "<Mod4>egrave"
gconftool-2 -t str --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/switch_to_workspace_8 "<Mod4>undersocre"
```

But when I configure this script to be run at startup, strangely it doesn't work.

Anyone have clues about how to solve this ?

Answer (score 6):

It appears not to be working on Natty + compiz (it works if you use metacity - `metacity --replace`). You can workaround this way:

You can use [wmctrl](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wmctrl) and make shortcuts for specifics commands.

## Basics commands:

**If you are using metacity:**
`wmctrl -d` to show all of your workspaces.
`wmctrl -s <workspace_name>` to change to a specific workspace.

**If you are using Compiz:**
you will have to do a trick because Compiz "workspaces" are actually Viewports of a single Workspace.

**Trick Instructions**

Check the output of `wmctrl -d` For example, mine is:

> 0  * DG: 4098x2304  VP: 1366,0  WA: 0,23 1366x745  N/A

This means that actually I have one Workspace of 4098 x 2304 instead of what I "think" I have (nine "workspaces", 3 x 3).
I was at what was supposed to be "workspace" 2, but actually I was at viewport (VP) 1366,0 (4098 / 3 = 1366) as showed by the output above.

So this is how it works: we take the whole Workspace and divide for the numbers of "workspaces" we "think" we have. In my case: 4098 / 3 = 1366 and 2304 / 3 = 768.

if I want to go to my "workspace" 1, the command is:
`wmctrl -o 0,0`

Then, if I want to go to my "workspace" 4, the command is:
`wmctrl -o 0,768`

if I want to go to my "workspace" 8, the command is:
`wmctrl -o 1366,1536`

if I want to go to my "workspace" 9, the command is:
`wmctrl -o 2732,1536`

Got it? ;-)

## Making the shortcuts

**1)** We will need [Compiz Settings Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager).

You can install these from the *Ubuntu Software Center* or by clicking [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)

**2)** Open Compiz (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `ccsm` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

**3)** Go to Commands and add for example `wmctrl -o 0,0` to one command

**4)** Then go to Keybindings and make the `<Super>+1` shortcut for it.

**5)** Repeat steps "3" and "4" for the others workspaces.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunalety, the update to ubuntu 11 proposed by the update manager really screwed my system, so I cannont test this for now. I'll try as soon as possible, but I'm disturbed to have to use this workaround because those shortcuts actually works on my work install (same ubuntu 10.04 64bits, same compiz).

Comment: I know that... Hope it can be fixed ASAP. Meanwhile you can workaround ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue with a few compiz settings. Here is my fixcompiz.sh that I run on each boot, with an entry in "Startup Applications" (I run 12.10), that resets some settings that get kicked back to default when the computer reboots.

As a side note, we should really submit a bug on this.

```
#!/bin/sh

#fix min and maximize    
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize "['<Super>Up']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings unmaximize "['<Super>Down']"

#fix switch to workspace shortcuts
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-1 "['<Primary><Shift><Alt>KP_Home']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-2 "['<Primary><Shift><Alt>KP_Up']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-3 "['<Primary><Shift><Alt>KP_Page_Up']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-4 "['<Primary><Shift><Alt>KP_Left']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-5 "['<Primary><Shift><Alt>KP_Begin']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-6 "['<Primary><Shift><Alt>KP_Right']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-7 "['<Primary><Shift><Alt>KP_End']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-8 "['<Primary><Shift><Alt>KP_Down']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-9 "['<Primary><Shift><Alt>KP_Page_Down']"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Presently, I installed another version of Ubuntu so I do not have the issue anymore. Anyway, could you be more precise with "I run on each boot" ? do you do it manually?

Comment: Added a note that I use "Startup Applications" to run this script on each boot. Hope that makes sense.